# Is it possible to get all users list which contain in the openfire?

Tags: list, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am doing an app chat in android by asmack with XMPP and want to  user client install the application he will be able to retrieve
The list of all the users which contain on the database.
This will allow to the client be able to select user from the List
and joined him to list friend one on one.
How can I do that?

If it not possible, how can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the WebManager Instance.

> ```
> WebManager webMan = ...;
>
> UserManager userMan = webMan.getUserManager();
>
> userMan.getUsers(); // Returns the user collection.
> ```

[UserManager API](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/UserManager.html)

From the collection list you can get all the users you wany.

Comment: What library should i use for WebManager. I am unable to import this package using asmack for android.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. why are you expecting smack API to give all the users that are in the server? you should use openfire API to give the information right? and the webmanager is present in the openfire API docs?

Comment: I want to get all users from openfire and check locally saved users. Then display and allow communications with available users. Something like that. So whatever i need to do guide me, i am not expert in this matter. Thanks :)

Comment: for webmanager you need to have openfire api available. I do't know the best practice, worst case you can get openfire api in your eclipse and use them. oR post an other question to find a decent way. This is a link on how to get openfire onto eclipse [https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1020].

Comment: ok this is throwing exception for sl4j inside WebManager Class of Openfire

Comment: Not so sure, but it looks like some logging fwk. see if you are missing any jar files for that?

Comment: webMan = ... what should this be equal to?

Comment: sl4j problem is solved. Now please tell me this. webMan = ? , webMan.getUserManager(); gives error. "The method getUserManager() from the type WebManager refers to the missing type UserManager"