# Get all users from Openfire server to android using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am creating a chat application on android and using asmack library for openfire xmpp. I am stuck at getting all users from server. I have tried many codes but none of them worked as i desired. What i need to do on server is manually add users to a group, then use

```
private ArrayList<String> getAllUsers(int num) {

    ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

    System.out.println("**Number Users: " + roster.getEntryCount());
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        users.add(entry.getName());
        System.out.println("User: " + entry.getName());
    }
    System.out.println("**Number Users: " + roster.getEntryCount());

    return users;
}
```

to get users inside the group i personally created. What i want to get is all the users available on openfire, or a way to add users to a specific group on openfire. How can I do that?

If I can get users by using groups then how to add users dynamically to a specific group?

Comment: Shared Groups? https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1619

Comment: this solves half my problem, why should i manually add users to a group? how to dynamically add them in a group using code, if groups is only chance!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135055/is-it-possible-to-get-all-users-list-which-contain-in-the-openfire/27233055#27233055
this should be ok i guess.

Comment: what is the library for web Manager?

Comment: I guess its in the openfire. see this link. https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/util/WebManager.html

Comment: If this is in openfire then which library to use? i am using asmack only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Roaster` as below.

```
        Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry rosterEntry : entries){

            System.out.println("xmpp.Roster.user "+ rosterEntry.getUser());
            System.out.println("xmpp.Roster.type "+ rosterEntry.getType().name());
            System.out.println("xmpp.Roster.presence "+ roster.getPresence(rosterEntry.getUser()).getType());
        }
```